# c++ program of sorting names

Tags: visual-c++

Instruction for program:
Read the list of names from “names.txt” in the format “First Last”.
Sort the names based upon typical alphabetic order of peoples names based upon last name then first name.
Write the sorted list to a file called “sortednames.txt” in the format “Last, First”.

Here's my code:  file data was stored in fullname array but now I am stuck on how to flip the first and last name in the array??

```
int main()
{
    const int MAXNAMES = 100;
    int value = 0;
    string fullname[MAXNAMES];

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("names.txt"); //open the file to excess the rainfall data
    if (inFile.fail()) // testing the file
        {
            cout << "Error opening file. Please check that the file currently `enter code here`exist" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }   
    cout << "File successfully open" << endl;
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        while(value < 100)
        {
            getline(inFile,fullname[value]);
            value++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Have you tried writing down the required steps in pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To flip the name around you could do the following:

```
string myString;
int spacePosition;

value = 0;
while(value < 100) {
   myString = fullname[value];
   spacePosition = myString.find(" ");
   fullname[value] = myString.substr(spacePostion) + " " + myString.substr(0, spacePostion -1);
}
```

Comment: its showing me error for spacePosition in this line.Why is that?fullname[value] = myString.substr(spacePostion) + " " + myString.substr(0, spacePostion -1);